# Non Recursive AVL Tree height

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

```
int get_height(struct avl_node *node)
{
    int height=0;
    if( node != NULL )
        height = 1 + max(get_height(node->left_child), 
                        get_height(node->right_child));
    return height;
}
```

I run AVL tree program in C. But at compile time generating 50 thousand random data that were different from each other in range of 1 to 50 thousand is too long. I find out that recursive form of function `get_height` is problem of too long compile time. I tired to make non-recursive form of `get_height` function to reduce compile time by using level traversal. But later I understand using level traversal is improper. is there correct non recursive form of `get_height`?

Comment: You can always "emulate" recursion using an explicit stack.

Comment: How can i do using stack?

Comment: Lots of related tutorials around, e.g. [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and). Google + have a go at doing it yourself.

Comment: avl_node should have a field that keeps track of the height, which you update during insert/delete operations.

Comment: @MattTimmermans it depends on the implementation; [some](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/AVLTreeImplementation.html) only have a balance factor.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog that's true, but if you're going to be calling get_height a lot then you should store the height instead.  If you cant modify the node, but you have a balance factor, then you can do get_height in O(log N) without recursion while traversing down to the left-most node

Comment: @MattTimmermans I agree; however we don't know whether OP is allowed to modify the implementation (it could be for a homework assignment based on a provided / pre-existing library).